# Getting Traceback and UnboundLocalError

Tags: python

Getting the following errors on my Python script that is supposed to read an CSV file with ticker symbols and price targets. To execute the script I need to type `python nameofscript.py nameoftickers.csv` as the CSV passes into the script.

The script’s logic is fairly simple: it takes a text file as an argument and reads the stock symbol, trigger value and the condition ( a for above and b for below ) from each line in the file. If the condition is met, then it sends an email to a predetermined email address and sends a push notification to your cellphone (in this case, an iPhone) through Pushover.

```
jovan@jovan-VirtualBox:~/pythonprojects$ python emailalerts.py symbols.csv 
Opening Google Finance URL...
Checking quotes for AAPL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "emailalerts.py", line 74, in <module>
    quote = quote_grab(linelst[0])
  File "emailalerts.py", line 30, in quote_grab
    return price #returns price as a float
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'price' referenced before assignment
```

The python script is below. I'm confused about the Traceback error but also the local variable. I've defined 'price' in the script.

```
import string, re, os, time, smtplib, sys
from urllib import urlopen
import httplib, urllib #used in the Pushover code


def quote_grab(symbol):

    baseurl = 'http://google.com/finance?q='
    urlData = urlopen(baseurl + symbol)

    print 'Opening Google Finance URL...'

    # Another option: namestr = re.compile('.*name:\"' + symbol + '\",cp:(.*),p:(.*?),cid(.*)}.*')
    namestr = re.compile('.*name:\"' + symbol + '\",cp:(.*),p:(.*?),cid(.*)') # "?" used as there is a second string "cid" in the page and the Match was being done up to that one. The "?" keeps it to the 1st occurrence.

    print 'Checking quotes for ' + symbol

    for line in urlData:

        m = re.match(namestr, line)

        if m:
            #Since the method m.group(2) returns a string in the form "xxxx", it cannot be converted to float,
            #therefore I strip the "" from that string and pass it to the float function.
            priceStr = m.group(2).strip('"')
            price = float(priceStr)


    urlData.close()
    return price #returns price as a float

def pushover(msg):

    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.pushover.net:443")
    conn.request("POST", "/1/messages.json",
        urllib.urlencode({
            "token": "________",
            "user": "________",
            "message": msg,
    }), { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" })
    conn.getresponse()


def send_email(sbjt, msg):
    fromaddr = '________'
    toaddrs = '________'
    bodytext = 'From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s' %(fromaddr, toaddrs, sbjt, msg)

    # Credentials (if needed)
    username = '________'
    password = '________' 

    # The actual mail sent
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username,password)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, bodytext)
    server.quit()

#------------------------
# Constants
file = sys.argv[1]

#------------------------

# Opens .cvs file, gets string at last line, converts it to list so that the comparison in the
# IF statement below can be done
csvFile = open(file, 'r')
body = 'Changes:\n'
chg = False

for line in csvFile:
    linelst = line.split(',')
    quote = quote_grab(linelst[0])

    if quote>float(linelst[1]) and linelst[2]==('a\n' or 'a'):
        body = body + 'Price for %s went up to %s (threshold = %s)\n' % (linelst[0], quote, linelst[1])
        chg = True
    if quote<float(linelst[1]) and linelst[2]==('b\n' or 'b'):
        body = body + 'Price for %s went down to %s (threshold = %s)\n' % (linelst[0], quote, linelst[1])
        chg = True

if chg:
    print 'sending email...'
    send_email('Stock Price Changes',body)
    print 'sending message to pushover...'
    pushover(body)

csvFile.close()
```

Comment: What value should `price` have if none of the lines match the regex pattern? (If you're thinking "that should never happen", are you sure?)

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `price` from function `quote_grab`, which can be undefined when `urlData` is empty so that the iteration by `for` does not happen or when `m` does not contain any Regex `match`. That's the reason for the `UnboundLocalError`.

You can define a default for `price` to return for the mentioned cases:

```
def quote_grab(symbol):
    ...
    ...
    price = 0.0  # default
    for line in urlData:
        ...
    return price
```